# React vertical slider using GSAP

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, gsap

I am new to GSAP, I want to create a vertical slider in react using GSAP
Here I found a reference link
https://codepen.io/chrispanayotoff/pen/qBbmLr

I need this same slider in react can anyone help?

Because of I am new to GSAP I don't know any of this properties & methods`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.